# Movable Teleportation Circle?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

Say a wizard makes a permanent teleportation circle (ptc) on a wooden platform. Then has the barbarian pick up and carry said platform to another location would it still work?

Comment: Yes dupe I don't know why that didn't show up when I was trying to find it for 30 min before this

Comment: That's ok, I could only find it because I knew it existed. It took me a couple of tries. Your question will help people find it in the future though.